# Firebase limitToFirst doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

I'm using Firebase to retrieve some data of Users. I need to retrieve **only one User** with 'gameSearching: true'.

I now got the following code:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://grootproject.firebaseio.com/Users");
    ref.orderByChild("gameSearching").equalTo(true).limitToFirst(1).on("child_added", function (data) {
        var yourself = firebase.getAuth().password.email.split("@", 1)[0];
        var opponent = data.key();

        setData(('Users/' + opponent + '/'), {gameSearching: false});
        setData(('Users/' + yourself + '/'), {gameSearching: false});

        console.log(opponent);
    });
```

When I run this code, the function will run twice.
I'm using `limitToFirst(1)` so I expect to retrieve only one user.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want a handler to only be executed once, use `.once('child_added'`. If you don't do that, it becomes a filtered *view* and data in that view may be updated over time. Firebase will also fire a `child_removed` event when that happens, so that only a single child is in the view at any time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### References

When you add a listener to Firebase with `on('child_added'` it will be called for every child that is created.

```
ref.on('child_added', function(s) { console.log(s.key()); });
```

This function will be triggered for all initial children **and** for any child that is added in the future.

In your Firebase this is the data:

```
hallo: gameSearching=false
sam_lous: gameSearching=true
test: gameSearching=false
test2: gameSearching=true
```

### Queries

When you add a listener to a query, it will be called for every child that falls into the query:

```
ref.orderByChild("gameSearching").equalTo(true).on("child_added‌​", function (s) { console.log(s.key()); })
```

So this will log all users that are searching for a game straight away **and** and user that later starts searching for a game.

```
sam_lous: gameSearching=true
test2: gameSearching=true
```

So when you call `user.update({ gameSearching: true })` on a user that wasn't searching for a game before, the function will be triggered. You're essentially seeing a list of all users that are searching for a game, and Firebase keeps that list up to date for you.

So let's say that user `test` starts searching for a game. When his `gameSeaching` is set to `true` you will receive a `child_added` event with:

```
test: gameSearching=true
```

Likewise when user test stops searching for a game (by a call `user.update({ gameSearching: false })`), Firebase will notify you of that through a `child_removed` event.

### Limited queries

We still have three users searching for a game:

```
sam_lous: gameSearching=true
test: gameSearching=true
test2: gameSearching=true
```

You add a listener to a query that has a limit on it:

```
ref.orderByChild("gameSearching").equalTo(true).limitToFirst(1).on("child_added‌​", function (s) { console.log(s.key()); })
```

This will fire a single `child_added` event for:

```
sam_lous: gameSearching=true
```

Now your code matches sam_lous to an opponent and sets the `gameSearching` value for sam_lous to false. So sam_lous no longer falls in the query. Firebase will still keep the query up to date, so it will:

1. send a `child_removed` event for sam_lous
2. send a `child_added` event for `test` (the next player that is searching for a game)

The thing to always keep in mind with Firebase is that you are not querying a database, you are synchronizing data. Since you asked Firebase for a synchronized list of a single player that is searching for a game, that is exactly what it does.